# Toggle component do not work on transcluded directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have one directive with toggle components on the view.
The configuration of toggle component is very simple:

```
input(type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle")
```

The directive works fine, but if this directive is loaded inside another directive the toggle component do not work anymore. :(

Can you guys help me?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could paste some code.

However, take into account that in angular when you have a hierarchy of directives they are executed bottom up. Therefore, if you are passing data to the child directive in the link function of the parent it will not work.

You can use the controllers in the directive instead of the link function to work around this issue.

Comment: I'm not using the link fun too. My issue is that the toggle component works with data bind. So when the directive is inside of another directive the toggle so not works.